# Is C++11 shared_ptr reference counting (increment / decrement) thread-safe / atomic?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, shared-ptr

Is C++11 shared_ptr reference counting (increment / decrement) thread-safe / atomic?

1. Please share insights on thread safety of C++11 shared_ptrs.
2. Are there any associated issues and possible data races.
3. Can it be used in async programming?

Answer (score 3):

If you have two threads, each with a `shared_ptr` to the same object, those threads' actions involving the reference count of the `shared_ptr` will be atomic. For instance, if both threads destroy their `shared_ptr` simultaneously and no other references to the object exist, exactly one of the threads will destroy the object.

Of course, going through a `shared_ptr` does not make operations on the object itself thread-safe. And if both threads are accessing the *same* `shared_ptr` (as opposed to different `shared_ptr`s to the same object), that access will not automatically be thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is thread safe.  The reference counting (increment / decrement) happens under const-qualified members (such as the source of a copy construction), and there is Chapter 17 wording that effectively says "simultaneous const-access shall be thread safe".